# Failing to push to heroku for nodejs web3 - it is trying to find web3@1.0.0-beta.42 postinstall

Tags: node.js, npm, heroku, web3js

I had pushed a node.js react with DApp with web3@1.0.0-beta-41 yesterday (2/6/19) and it worked. Since this morning, when I try to push the same codes it comes up with

> web3@1.0.0-beta.42 postinstall
> C:\BaandaDev\baandadev-03\client\node_modules\web3
>
> > node angular-patch.js module.js:549
> > throw err;
> > ^ Error: Cannot find module 'C:\BaandaDev\baandadev-03\client\node_modules\web3\angular-patch.js'
> > (Please disregard baanda ... those are my directory names but the
> > error is emerging from node modules)

Why is it looking for web3@1.0.0-beta.42 when I am not even asking for it?

I have reduced the version till web3@1.0.0.beta-37 and heroku still looks for beta.42 angular patch (I am not even using angular). The worst thing is ... it worked yesterday.

The only thing I can think of is, Ethereum released web3@1.0.0-beta.42 yesterday. But, it does not explain why heroku would look for a patch for something else.

Interestingly, when I clone the one that is working in heroku in my local machine using something like heroku git:clone -a baandadev03-t2 and then run npm install to re-instead it in my local machine, it throws the same problem in my local machine. However, if I npm i --save webe3@1.0.0-beta.41 manually, it does deploy without a hitch.

Suspect: npm install  (generic that install node-modules from package.json is broken for  web3 somehow). That is why it is breaking in heroku as well as in local. But, that's a suspect only.

`$ git push heroku master` (and heroku should push it in and not look for modules I am not asking for).

Answer (score 0):

Likely it is because of web3 npm is breaking. They (web3) have release version web1.0.0-beta.40 to 43 in 3 days. But, I also realized that generic npm install, used for generating node-modules from package.json (node.js), is breaking on web3 on both side. In heroku after push when they try to gen the node-modules. And, when I clone the version from heroku into my own laptop, it cry at the same place (while creating node module at web3). Both places are looking for angular library that it cannot find (I do not know why they would do that - a bug?). And, even when I specify much lower version of web3, it still looks for it that it never did in the past.

I have reported the bug and hope they fix it quickly. I removed all web3 reference from my application and it went into heroku nice and fine. But, that is not good when app depends on smart contracts ... right :)?